# How to merge two metrics in microstrategy visual insights?

Tags: microstrategy

I have created those line charts in `microstrategy 10 visual insights`, but I want them to look as a merged chart. Can anyone help me with that. How to do so?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to move the "Metric Names" to "Break By" and them to "Color By".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result by using the `combo chart` from the visualization gallery. Also make sure that the metrics(here `incoming` and `outgoing`) are in different axes like left and right axes.
Drag and drop the `metric names` into the **Color By** box to give different colors to those metrics (i.e., `incoming` and `outgoing`).